# Angular 2 how to make a nested observable

Tags: http, angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to write up our httpService, it should have a post method that checks to see if a cookie exists with an auth token, if it does then it should append the auth header and make the post request.

However if the cookie doesn't exist I need to load a local json file that contains the token and use it to create the cookie, then append the auth header and make the post request.

The issue I'm having is that if the cookie doesn't exist I need to make a observable wait for another observable. I had thought the solution was to use switchMap, but that doesn't play well with .subscribe which is necessary for the http.post request to initialize.

```
  private makePostRequest(address: string, payload: any, callback: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(address, payload, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(callback)
      .catch(( error: any ) => this.handleError(error));
  }

  public post(address: string, payload: any, callback: any): Observable<any>     {
       if (this.hasOAuth2()) {
         this.appendHeader(this.cookieService.get('oauth2'));
         return this.makePostRequest(address, payload, callback);
       } else if (this.isLocalhost()) {
         return this.setAuthCookie()
           .switchMap(() => this.makePostRequest(address, payload, callback));
       } else {
         return this.handleError('Could not locate oauth2 cookie');
       }
  }

  private setAuthCookie(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./json/token.json')
      .map((res: Response) => {
        let oauth2: any = res.json();
        this.cookieService.set('oauth2', oauth2.access_token, oauth2.expiration);
        this.appendHeader(oauth2.access_token);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('No dev token was found', error);
        return Observable.throw(error);
      });
  }
```

Update: Where this gets weird is that more or less the exact game code works correctly with a get request.

```
  private makeGetRequest(address: string, callback: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(address, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(callback)
      .catch(( error: any ) => this.handleError(error));
  }

  public get(address: string, callback: any): Observable<any> {
      if (this.hasOAuth2()) {
        this.appendHeader(this.cookieService.get('oauth2'));
        return this.makeGetRequest(address, callback);
      } else if (this.isLocalhost()) {
        return this.setAuthCookie()
          .switchMap(() => this.makeGetRequest(address, callback));
      } else {
        return this.handleError('Could not locate oauth2 cookie');
      }
  }
```

Solution: I wasn't subscribing to the httpService.post observable so it wasn't ever being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty `.subscribe()` to your second case:

```
return this.setAuthCookie()
          .map(() => { })
          .switchMap(() => { // I need to switchMap due to the http.get request in the setAuthCookie method
            this.makePostRequest(address, payload, callback).subscribe(); // Again I need this or the post request won't be made
          }).subscribe(); // <--- here
```

It will activate the http call.

Answer (score 0):

I had never subscribed to my httpService.post observable so it was never being initialized. Adding the later subscribe calls was causing it to be initialized incorrectly.